# Issue with Facebook JS API, revokeAuthorization

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am trying to integrate FB connect into our user profile screen.  Although, I'm having an issue with FB.ApiClient.revokeAuthorization.

http://pastie.org/921942

The basic problem is that I revoke the auth at line 44 after the user clicks the disconnect button.

After that, all subsequent API calls don't have a valid session to even check user status.  I've tried wrapping blocks in a FB.Connect.forceSessionRefresh block, but then the code will never be called at all.

I'm not sure what the proper workflow should be for this purpose.  Right now it's basically...

1. User arrives at profile NOT
   connected to the application.
2. User clicks on the connect button.
3. Once connected, DOM manipulation
   occurs to hide the connect button
   and add in a disconnect button.
4. User clicks on the disconnect
   button.
5. User's authorization to the
   application is revoked and (it
   seems) the API session to the FB
   server is invalidated.
6. DOM manipulation occurs to hide the
   disconnect button and readd the
   connect button.
7. User clicks on the connect button.
8. Once connected, the
   FB.Connect.get_loggedInUser() doesn't
   return the actual user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just use the facebook api of `$facebook->logout()`.  By placing `$facebook->logout()` it will either display the "LOGOUT" button if they are logged in, or show the login button if they are logged out.

Another option is to use the FB JS library and do an onClick event of `FB.logout(function(response){ window.location = 'redirecturl'});`

Comment: Those methods are not available in the Old Javascript SDK.  If you note the code, it is using the old SDK - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/ .  Although really, I rewrote all the code with the new SDK prior to your answer anyway.  I'll go ahead and give you the bounty just to close the question out.

Comment: @BBonifield Would you mind posting your code for anyone else that is having the same issue as you?